# Can I run 2 versions of InDesign with the interface in 2 different languages? (Mac, Adobe CC)

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-creative-suite

Due to working for a non-English publication, the version of InDesign that I am using at work is in another language, however I myself use the English version of InDesign for my other projects and it's just quite a hassle to have to communicate with the different teams.

Is there anyway to run 2 different versions of InDesign on a Mac with the interface in 2 different languages?
And if no, what is the best way to toggle between two different UI languages for InDesign, AND **only for InDesign**, not for my other Adobe apps?

Comment: I don't know about the languages.. but I can launch ID CS6 and CC at the same time. I Imagine you can launch CC 2017 and CC 2021 at the same time... but probably not 2 copies of the same version.

Comment: Hey Scott, to my knowledge, that's how it works too but I can't seem to download any version of InDesign from before CC 2021 probably because I only just activated my license this year...

Comment: Yeah Adobe no longer offers legacy versions. Due to the (horrible) subscription  format, all CC versions are "get 'em when released or never get em." You can only have multiple CC versions if you had an older version before updating. As far as I know, there's no way to acquire CC 2014-2021 now.  Only other thing I can think of is a dual boot system or virtual machines through something like [Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/pd/general/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxaipiuv79AIVBk6GCh36nQT6EAAYASAAEgIbC_D_BwE) (no affiliation).

Comment: @Scott - actually in the CC app you can find older versions of InDesign CC. and other applications You have to click the three dots, and choose "Other Versions" [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/IxDcw9c). Goes back to version 16.4 currently.

Comment: I stand corrected @BillyKerr .. it's been ages since I launched that CC app. `:)`

Comment: Virtual machine.

Comment: @Scott - yeah I don't open it often either, but I remember having to do it once. I had foolishly upgraded to brand new release of Photoshop only to discover it was too buggy and unstable to use, and wanted to revert back to an earlier version. Took me ages to find the option to find an older download. It's quite well hidden.

Answer (score 6):

Set up another [Mac] User account & use Fast User Switching.

Each user can then set their own prefs, which won't affect the other.
Both versions can be running simultaneously, also without affecting the other [so long as you have sufficient memory/disk/scratch space].
Downside is switching is slightly slower than just between 2 apps - just timed it at about 5 seconds rather than <1, so it's not prohibitively slow.
Upside is it's exactly the same version/install of InDesign, so there's no Adobe account or version hoop-jumping.

Comment: Excellent point. I so wish one could use fast user switching for a dual boot system (each user booted to a different OS version.) `:)`

Comment: @Scott - …for everything else, there's Parallels ;))

Comment: This sounds pretty ideal, I'll give this a try, thanks a lot Tetsujin!!